# Can we generate a UUID field in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I need to make a custom field in elasticsearch just like the **"_id"** field. Also, I need to store the **`UUID`** value (AV2oDy5F6POrheehhR9d) in that field.

Currently, I am storing a URL in the "_id" field. The elastic version I am using is **2.3.3** and kibana is **4.5**

The two fields will be like this according to my view :

```
    {
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.9965843,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "testIndex",
        "_type": "testType",
        "_id": "http://www.gmail.com",
        "_score": 0.9965843,
        "_source": {
          -----------------------------
          "uuid":"AV2oDy5F6POrheehhR9d"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Can someone help me on this ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could use the `set` processor in a pipeline to copy the _id field over if that was a UUID, otherwise you have to pass the UUID externally, just as any other field.

Comment: @alr I'm afraid pipelines are not available in ES 2.x. Though my question would be, why destroying ES' convention to replace the `_id` field by a url, and then creating a `uuid` field? Wouldn't it be simpler to keep the `uuid` into the `_id` field and create inside the document a `url` field?

Comment: @Adonis yesterday . I need url to be unique while adding documents. and also i need unique id.

Comment: By default `_id` is unique (except if you override ES' default behavior), now it is your responsibility to create unique urls, so instead of destroying the `_id` field, you could simply do 1. Create your unique url by whatever mean you see fit. 2. Use that url and push the "unique" part to the `_id` field. 3. Document that so others know that the `_id` field is used to create the url